# Symmetry which shows that the magnitude of electric field due to infinitely large sheet doesn't depend on perpendicular distance from the sheet

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, symmetry, gauss-law, coulombs-law

The magnitude of electric field due to a uniformly charged, infinitely large sheet is
$$E = \frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0}$$

($\sigma$ is surface charge density)

It is a constant for all points in space, it doesn't even depend on perpendicular distance from the sheet. The textbook "NCERT Physics Textbook for Class 12 Part 1" asked to find a symmetry which shows that the magnitude of electric field doesn't depend on perpendicular distance from the sheet.

I first thought of the following **:** Say a point is kept at distance from the sheet. If you increase the distance of the point from the sheet and then start zooming out, it basically becomes the same as before and so the field should be the same ( basically, due to the infinite size of plane, there is no sense of scale ).

But then, by the same logic, the magnitude of field due to an infinitely long uniformly charged wire should also not depend on perpendicular distance from wire, but it does (it is inversely proportional to it). So what is that symmetry?

And also, where did I go wrong?

Here, I give the corresponding text from the book for reference *(no need to read)*:

*"Consider, for example an infinite uniform sheet of charge (uniform surface charge density)   along the y-z plane. This system is unchanged if (a) translated parallel to the y-z plane in any direction. (b) rotated about the x-axis through any angle. As the system is unchanged under such symmetry operation, so must its properties be. In particular, in this example, the electric field must be unchanged.*

*Translation symmetry along the y-axis shows that the electric field must be the same
at a point (0, y1, 0) as at (0, y2, O). Similarly translational symmetry along the z-a shows that the electric field at two point (0, 0, z1) and (0. 0. z2) must be the same. By using rotation symmetry around the x-axis, we can conclude that E must be perpendicular to the y-z plane, that is, it must be parallel to the x-direction. **Try to think of a symmetry now which will tell you that the magnitude of the electric field is a constant, independent of the x-coordinate.** It thus turns out that the magnitude of the electric field due to a uniformly charged infinite conducting sheet is the same at all points in space. The direction, however, is opposite of each other om either side of the sheet."*

Answer (score 0):

> If you increase the distance of the point from the sheet and then start zooming out, it basically becomes the same as before and so the field should be the same ( basically, due to the infinite size of plane, there is no sense of scale)

Very good. But you need to be a bit more careful in your analysis -- and that will show the difference between a sheet and a wire.

Suppose you wish to [apply Gauss' law to deduce the electric field](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/06%3A_Gauss%27s_Law/6.04%3A_Applying_Gausss_Law). Consider how the enclosed charge changes with the size of rescaled region. That should help you understand how rescaling symmetry works for the sheet but not for the wire.

Another way to think about this is that any wire must have a finite diameter (cannot assume it to be infinitely thin), and that length scale breaks the rescaling symmetry even though you can zoom out and incorporate more length of wire into your Gaussian volume.

Answer (score 0):

The symmetry which the book the book talks about is the shape of the object containing the charge. For e.g. Sphere has spherical symmetry ,and cone has cylindrical symmetry. You might have noticed that spheres follow inverse square law for gravity and coulombic interactions. This is attributed to the geometry of the shape. For a objects with planar symmetry things work differently.